# Appcelerator won't create build when I am using card.io module, module from gittio is com.likelysoft.cardio

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, card.io

I have added module com.likelysoft.cardio from gittio and trying to create build but it's showing me following error :

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/---\ --.build/Debug-iphoneos/--\ --.build/Obje  normal/arm64/--\ -- normal arm64
[ERROR] :   Ld build/--\ --.build/Debug-iphoneos/--\ --.build/Objects-normal/armv7/--\ -- normal armv7
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
```

But when I am trying to build project by removing this module from tiapp.xml, it works. (it's create build).

Also by adding this module  it works on simulator. :(
 where Actually I am going wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to make some changes in module.xconfig file ( located at -> modules -> iPhone-> com.likelysoft.cardio -> 1.0.0 -> module.xconfig) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by Updating my xcode to 7 and Appcelerator SDK to 5.0.2 GA and it's working fine now, and I can create build now. :)